# Please post good answers- is it a request or an order?

Tags: phrase-request, imperative-sentences, semantic-roles

> **Please post good answers**

Is the above sentence an order or a request?

Since it is an imperative, it may be an order.

Since the sentence begins with *please*, it seems to be a request.

I think it is an order because we can not make an order a request by simply placing the word *please* at the beginning of an imperative sentence.

Michael Swan in his **Practical English Usage**  on page number 427 under the title 429: Please and Thank you says:

Note that *please* does not change an order into a request. compare:

> **stand over there.** order)
>
> **please stand over there( more polite order)**
>
> **could you stand over there, please?**( more polite request)

I believe that Michael Swan is a world famous Native English grammarian.

Comment: Why do you think it is an order?

Comment: I`d definitely say it is a request, if it were an order it would be something like: "post good answers!"

Comment: @Englishmonger  In your own native language, from the text alone is it easy to distinguish between a request and an order?  In English it is not so easy -- in this case it all depends on the *tone* with which it is stated.  A strong, commanding tone makes it an order.  A softer, more entreating tone makes it a request.  Michael Swan may be correct, but only in the context of his specific example.

Comment: @Englishmonger A sentence/phrase like "Please post good answers" needs context to be understood as either an order or a request. If someone points a gun at you and says *"Please post good answers"* - it is an order. In contrast, if a non-native says *"Please post good answers with lots and lots of details so I can understand every aspect of the answer"*, then that would be a request or a plea for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An order is an imperative instruction, given by someone with the authority to do so, to a subordinate person, often in the context of a 'discipline service' such as a military organisation, or police or fire services. A parent might give an order to his or her child. There will usually be consequences, such as punishment, for disobeying an order. A key feature of an order is that it is given by somebody who has authority. A strongly worded instruction by someone who lacks the authority to give it is not a valid order.

> If someone in authority gives you an order, they tell you to do
>   something.

[Order (Collins Dictionary)](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/order)

A request is made by politely or formally asking for something. There need be no difference in seniority between the person making the request, and the hearer. The hearer is free to decline or disregard the request.

> A request is the act of politely or officially asking for something:

[Request (Collins Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/order)

"Please post good answers" must be a request, because it is phrased politely, and a person placing text on a website does not have the authority to order the readers to do things.

Comment: @ Michaei Harvey, I can not agree with you.It is an order in a polite way.It is never a request.

Comment: @Englishmonger it seems that you are looking for an answer that confirms your opinion. That is not a question. An order has little to do with the phrasing, but the seniority or hierarchy of the parties. Have you never seen the line "...and that's an order" ? Perhaps you are confusing an "order" with an "imperative".

Comment: According to Michael Swan, It is an order. I am sure of that.I am not expecting an answer that confirms my opinion.It looks like a request but it is not a request.

Comment: I do not see any link to, or quotation from, this 'Michael Swan' of whom you speak, which might support your assertion.

Comment: @Englishmonger in that case it is opinion. "Post good answers" is imperative, "Please post good answers" is not, nor is "It would be helpful to post a good answer". Any of them can be an order.